# Exporting Dtsx package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have some issues exporting the dtsx maintainance plans from current server. current server is SQL Server 2008 and Os 2008 r2. [image]Seeing below error.

Please help me resolving this. thank you.

Comment: Post the error(s) as text, that is what they are after all.

Comment: Also, SQL Server 2008 is now completely unsupported, and you should be looking at upgrade paths as soon as possible, if not already.